# Running iPhone App on iPad/iPad Simulator fails

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I recently created an iPhone app using Xcode and storyboards. The app works perfectly on a real iPhone and the iPhone simulator, but when I test it on the iPad simulator or an actual iPad something happens with the application, and I can't figure out what went wrong...

**iPhone Simulator**

[image: iPhone Simulator]

**iPad Simulator**

[image: iPad Simulator]

Comment: How are you laying out the elements?  This could be a struts problem.  Do you allow rotation of the UI?  If you enable it and rotate the iphone, are things still layed out properly, or do they go all wonky?

Comment: No I don't allow rotation of the iphone, but that is because the screen messes up like that when I do so even on the iPhone.

Comment: Need some code. Without code it's hard to tell some useful.

Comment: Do you use storyboards? If so, do you have two storyboards, one for iPhone and another for iPad?

Comment: @Adam I used two storyboards before, but then I deleted the ipad story board, and now I only have the iphone storyboard...

Comment: You need to have two separate storyboards. If you have set the iPhone storyboard for iPad, that might be the reason of your problem.

Comment: @Adam But I basically want to run my iphone only app on my ipad simply because I don't have an iPhone...

Comment: I'm guessing: you need to change your target settings from Universal to iPhone.

Comment: How does it look at 1x on the ipad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by clicking on my main Project name in Xcode. Then I selecte the tab "info" and I changed the Main Story Board File Base Name (iPad) to my storyboard. Then it worked perfectly!

Answer (score -1):

This happens to a number of apps in many occasions, my soloutions are:

1: Try making a separate app but change the app's code from the original app, if by any chance a new code would work, try uploading this app but label it by the originally name but adding 'V.2 or iPad V.1'.

2: If the soloutions above isn't working have you asked a friend or a person you know with a different version of the iPad or a different branded simulator if the app works. If it does, it means your code can either not enable in your version of the iPad or stimulator or that your code must've been changed in download (Which is rare but does happen.) and I suggest re-buy or re-download your app. If it didn't work for your friends or some friends had it working while others didn't (Soloution is best if your friends had different versions of the iPad or stimulator) I think there is a possibility of it being a 'MultiCrash&MultiUsabls'' which is a type of gaming on Mac Products which the app can be simultaneously downloaded by many users who own different versions of iPhones, iPads and iPods and some of them manage to have the app work while it doesn't for others, you should save the code in a file, then delete the already made game, re-upload and see if it works on the iPad and iPad stimulator.